# diophantine linear equation with condition on the sum of coefficients

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

I am trying to solve the following diophantine equation

```
x*a + y*b == c
```

where a,b,c are integers and the absolute value of their sums is, for instance, 4. Then I like to plot the results in the x,y plane.

Is it possible with `FindInstance` or `Reduce` ? Thanks.

Comment: `Reduce[{x*a + y*b == c, Abs[a + b + c] == 4}, {x, y}, Integers]` returns a result, albeit somewhat complex. Perhaps you could start from there.

Comment: What do you mean by "plot the results in the x,y plane"? What kind of plot do you envision? What will be the independent and dependent variable? What parameters?